# Hash each row of pandas dataframe column using apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hash, apply

I'm trying to hash each value of a python 3.6 pandas dataframe column with the following algorithm on the dataframe-column ORIG:

```
HK_ORIG = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(str(df.ORIG).encode("UTF-8")).digest())
```

However, the above mentioned code does not hash each value of the column, so, in order to hash each value of the df-column ORIG, I need to use the apply function. Unfortunatelly, I don't seem to be good enough to get this done.

I imagine it to look like the following code:

```
df["HK_ORIG"] = str(df['ORIG']).encode("UTF-8")).apply(hashlib.sha1)
```

I'm looking very much forward to your answers!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: define it as a function and then: `df['ORIG'].apply(func)`

Answer (score 5):

You can either create a named function and apply it - or apply a lambda function. In either case, do as much processing as possible withing the dataframe.

A lambda-based solution:

```
df['ORIG'].astype(str).str.encode('UTF-8')\
          .apply(lambda x: base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(x).digest()))
```

A named function solution:

```
def hashme(x):
    return base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(x).digest())
df['ORIG'].astype(str).str.encode('UTF-8')\
          .apply(hashme)
```