# How to find the hash value of the rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hash

I tried this code from a previously asked question here on Stack overflow:

```py
    def hashme(x):
        return base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(x).digest())
    df['ORIG'].astype(str).str.encode('UTF-8')\
              .apply(hashme)
```

However this code is for columns. I need to find the hash of each row.

[Link to previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178961/hash-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-column-using-apply)

I tried using **iloc** to get just the rows but it kept giving me an error.

I would also like to know how to loop the row number so that I can find the hash value of an 'n' number of rows.

I'm a total novice at Python, so this is really confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just query for hash value:

```py
df.loc[df['ORIG'] == hashme("my_value"))]
```